# Spring R2DBC - Connect to a SQL Server Database using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

trying to connect with MSSQL server with windows authentication using reactive(R2DBC) JDBC driver

```
#Data Source Configuration
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:mssql://host:port
    name: dbname
    properties:
       domain: xyz
       authenticationScheme: NTLM
       integratedSecurity: true
       trustServerCertificate: false
       encrypt: true
    username: user
    password: password
    pool:
      enabled: true
      initial-size: 100
      max-size: 500
      max-idle-time: 30m
      validation-query: SELECT
```

getting following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is io.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory$MssqlPermissionDeniedException: [18456] [S0001] Login failed for user 'user'.
```

Comment: Does that driver even support NTLM?

Comment: according to github, no NTLM is supported https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql/issues/101

Answer (score 0):

Try using `validation-query: SELECT 1`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why this may solve the OP's problem.